# Testing logical validity

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

My understanding of a logical formula being valid is that it concludes something, for example:

$[(A \rightarrow B) \wedge (B \rightarrow C)] \rightarrow [A \rightarrow C]$ is logically valid. (I may be mixing this up with rule of inference)

I'm trying to understand if a method I found is able to determine if a formula is logically valid.
Using elementary algebra it is possible to establish the following relations

$a \wedge b = ab \qquad $and $\qquad ¬a = 1-a$

From these it follows that

$a \rightarrow b = 1-a+ab$

where $+$ and $\times$ are being used in the everyday sense.

---

The method:

Using the above relations it is possible to convert the original statement into elementary algebra.

$[(A \rightarrow B) \wedge (B \rightarrow C)] \rightarrow [A \rightarrow C]$

Evaluating the 'outermost' implication yields:

$1-[(A \rightarrow B) \wedge (B \rightarrow C)] + [(A \rightarrow B) \wedge (B \rightarrow C)][A \rightarrow C]$

Evaluating the next implications yields

$1-[(1-a+ab) \wedge (1-b+bc)] + [(1-a+ab) \wedge (1-b+bc)][1-a+ac]$

Evaluating the ANDs yields

$1-[(1-a+ab)(1-b+bc)] + [(1-a+ab)(1-b+bc)][1-a+ac]$

Expanding the parentheses gives

$1-[1-a-b+ab+bc] + [1-a-b+ab+bc][1-a+ac]$

Expanding the brackets gives

$1 - [1-a-b+ab+bc] + [1-a-b+ab+bc]$

Which simplifies to

$1$

---

I am interpreting this 1 as saying that the original formula was logically valid. Is this a correct interpretation? If not, what is this $1$ telling me? I know that it means that for all possible inputs into the logical expression, the expression holds, does this imply validity?

Comment: Apart from your use of the word "idempotency", you are quite correct (in the final step, the usual jargon is that you are multiplying out and cancelling like terms; there aren't any idempotent operators left).

Comment: Can you please show how you get to 1 from that expression?  I tried to multiply it all out and didn't get to 1 ....

Comment: @Bram28 I've put a bit more detail in.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you, I didn't want anyone to read $a \times ab$ as $a^2b$. So this is an appropriate method for determining if a formula is valid?

Comment: @BenCrossley Thanks!  i get it: $(1-a+ab)(1-b+bc)=1-b+bc-a+ab-abc+ab-ab^2+abc$. Then by idempotence, $ab^2=ab$, and then you get $1-b+bc-a+ab$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am interpreting this 1 as saying that the original formula was logically valid. Is this a correct interpretation? If not, what is this $1$ telling me? I know that it means that for all possible inputs into the logical expression, the expression holds, does this imply validity?

Yes.

A valid statement is a tautology.

That is that it is valued as true (ie $1$) for all interpretations of its literals.

Comment: hopefully quick follow up question. Does Godel's incompleteness theorem for first order logic implies that this is impossible for for first order logic?

Comment: @BenCrossley The incompleteness claims do NOT apply to first order logic (there exist two of them).  From what I've read, Goedel's doctoral thesis involved a proof of a completeness theorem for first-order logic.

Answer (score 0):

Two comments.

First, $(1-a+ab)(1-b+bc)$ works out to $1-b+bc-a+ab-abc+ab-ab^2+ab^2c$

This only works out to $1-a-b+ab+bc$ if $ab^2 = ab$ and $ab^2c=abc$ ... which you call 'Idempotence. Which is of course fine for a boolean algebra, but you can *not* say that:

> $+$ and $\times$ are being used in the everyday sense.

or that this is

> elementary algebra

Also, when working this out, you get:

$[1-a-b+ab+bc][1-a+ac]=$

$1-a-b+ab+bc-a+a^2+ab-a^2b-abc+ac-a^2c-abc+a^2bc+abc^2$

Now, again you need the non-every-day-sense and non-elementary-algebra move of Idempotence to equate this to:

$1-a-b+ab+bc-a+a+ab-ab-abc+ac-ac-abc+abc+abc$

and only now do you get to:

$1-a-b+ab+bc$

Moreover, how is this any simpler than Boolean algebra?

Here is your solution all written out:

$[(A \rightarrow B) \wedge (B \rightarrow C)] \rightarrow [A \rightarrow C]=$

$1-[(A \rightarrow B) \wedge (B \rightarrow C)] + [(A \rightarrow B) \wedge (B \rightarrow C)][A \rightarrow C]=$

$1-[(1-a+ab) \wedge (1-b+bc)] + [(1-a+ab) \wedge (1-b+bc)][1-a+ac]=$

$1-[(1-a+ab)(1-b+bc)] + [(1-a+ab)(1-b+bc)][1-a+ac]=$

$1-[1-b+bc-a+ab-abc+ab-ab^2+ab^2c] + [1-b+bc-a+ab-abc+ab-ab^2+ab^2c)][1-a+ac]=$

$1-[1-b+bc-a+ab-abc+ab-ab+abc] + [1-b+bc-a+ab-abc+ab-ab+abc][1-a+ac]=$

$1-[1-a-b+ab+bc] + [1-a-b+ab+bc][1-a+ac]=$

$1-[1-a-b+ab+bc] + [1-a-b+ab+bc-a+a^2+ab-a^2b-abc+ac-a^2c-abc+a^2bc+abc^2]=$

$1-[1-a-b+ab+bc] + [1-a-b+ab+bc-a+a+ab-ab-abc+ac-ac-abc+abc+abc]=$

$1 - [1-a-b+ab+bc] + [1-a-b+ab+bc]=$

$1$

By contrast, here is the Boolean algebra solution:

$[(A \rightarrow B) \land (B \rightarrow C)] \rightarrow [A \rightarrow C] =$

$\neg [(\neg A \lor B) \land (\neg B \lor C)] \lor [\neg A \lor C] =$

$\neg (\neg A \lor B) \lor \neg (\neg B \lor C) \lor [\neg A \lor C] =$

$( A \land \neg B) \lor (B \land \neg C) \lor \neg A \lor C =$

$\neg B \lor B \lor \neg A \lor C =$

$\top \lor \neg A \lor C =$

$\top$

Seems to me the Boolean algebra method is a good bit more efficient.

In sum. Yes, your method works ... but you have to assume Idempotence, and it is *not* everyday or elementary algebra. And second, classical Boolean algebra is a good bit more efficient.

Comment: I did have idempotent in my original question.

Comment: Also, it very much is every day algebra simply because literals are restricted to values in {0,1}. Idempotency is a property of elementary algebra on this set. Nothing extra is needed.

Comment: @BenCrossley Since you were working with $1$, $+$, $-$, and $\times$, I figured that by 'every day' algebra you meant something akin to number algebra. But as soon as you restrict yourself to $\{0,1\}$ it is a boolean algebra ... which I don't regard as 'everyday' or 'elementary' algebra. And there are (non-standard) boolean where idempotence does not hold. So, in the end, you really just end up with a classical logical boolean algebra ... except that using what you used for the conditional, it's not as efficient as the boolean algebras we have already.

Comment: That's fair. The reason I'm using it is because I found it myself and have never learned logic. I believe it has 2 advantages over Boolean notation too. The first is that the lowest homogeneity term is always a solution and the second is setting each variable to 0.5 and multiplying the expression by $2^l$, where $l$ is the number of literals, provides the number of solutions.

Comment: E.g. $a \rightarrow b$ is $1-a+ab$, set each literal to 0.5 gives $1-0.5+0.25 = 0.75$. Multiplying by $2^2$ gives $3$ which is the number of assignments of a and b that evaluate to true.

Comment: @BenCrossley Hey, that's pretty cool you found that yourself: Kudos!  And I'll have to look into those two claims of yours ... that *does* look interesting.

Comment: If you notice anything cool please let me know. I wanted to try and understand P vs NP and ended up with an idea for #P using this.

Comment: did you verify my claim? I’ve proven it already but nice to know someone else has too.

Comment: @BenCrossley Sorry, been too busy with other things .. :(